# Python not removing words but works for single letter

Tags: python

I have this project where I'm supposed to remove some word from a statement using code below:

```
forbidden_words = ["And","is","to","from","the"]
f = "And thus brought us to this conclusion from the existing inference"

h = []
for i in f:
    if i not in forbidden_words:
        h.append(i)
"".join(h)
```

Output: `'And thus brought us to this conclusion from the existing inference'`

Expected output: `'thus brought us this conclusion existing inference'`

I'm not sure why but it works well for single letter but not a single word, suppose the code below:

```
forbidden_words = ["u","t","c","b","a"]
f = "And thus brought us to this conclusion from the existing inference"

h = []
for i in f:
    if i not in forbidden_words:
        h.append(i)
"".join(h)
```

Output: `'And hs rogh s o his onlsion from he exising inferene'`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split `f` on spaces in order to iterate over the words:

```py
h = []
for word in f.split():
    if word not in forbidden_words:
        h.append(word)
" ".join(h)
```

Or, with a generator expression:

```py
" ".join(word for word in f.split() if word not in forbidden_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
forbidden_words = ["And","is","to","from","the"]
f = "And thus brought us to this conclusion from the existing inference"
for words in forbidden_words:
     f = ''.join(f.split(words))
f = re.sub(' +', ' ', f)
```

Comment: check your output, its wrong

Answer (score -1):

You have to iterate over a list of strings not on the string as shown below.

```py
forbidden_words = ["And","is","to","from","the"]
sentence = "And thus brought us to this conclusion from the existing inference".split()

filt_text = [ w  for w in sentence if w not in forbidden_words]

filt_sentence = ' '.join(filt_text)

print(filt_sentence )
```